# grep command sometimes won't work on mac os x

Tags: grep

I'm getting this error sometimes. Same user, same bash profile, same export but sometimes return commend not found.

```
bash-3.2# find . | grep httpd.conf
bash:  grep: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a common but subtle problem. Depending on keyboard layout, you may use the <kbd>alt</kbd> key to create a `|` pipe.

If you accidentally hold down <kbd>alt</kbd> for too long, and hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> together, you'll get what looks to a human like a space after the pipe, but is not the same character. <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> is a non-breaking space (like `&nbsp;` in HTML).

Make sure when you type a `|` pipe, that you have fully released the <kbd>alt</kbd> key before pressing <kbd>space</kbd>. Then the terminal will correctly recognise the `grep` command.

Comment: I don't understand neither the question nor the answer

Comment: My point is that it is very unclear what is the problem you are facing. `find . | grep httpd.conf` seems to be a correct command (even though `find -name "httpd.conf"` would be better and this issue with the keys and spaces does not make much sense to me (maybe because I am not in Mac OSX so I cannot reproduce).

Comment: It's look like correct but not. Space doesn't equal Alt + Space. Pressing Alt + Space instead of Space casual mistake when i type this command throw together.